# How to make my mobile app to work more faster when web services made from drupal7 REST services

Tags: 7, services

We did an app based on drupal web services(REST server). The thing is the app is very slow on the device. The reason for this may be, the app requires 3 webservices to load initially. lile

```
http://myapps/api/node?parameters[type]=Company
```

From the above web service i will get all node under CCk company. then to get the details of the node i need to pass another url as `http://myapps/api/node/5` and then to get the taxonomy term to which ths company belongs to i need to pass another url. there by it is taking much time to load. Is there any solution to make my app faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm used to create my own resources / module then i can send all the information i need with custom query / joins, following the next tutorial:

http://drupal.org/node/1246470

Also on my module i could enable cache etag and then programming on mobile device the http client with etag support.